# Error generating Rollup js bundle in typescript with socket.io client, "'io' is not exported (..."

Tags: typescript, socket.io, rollupjs

I'm getting error when trying generate a bundle with rollup in a typescript project that imports socket.io (v3). I started with a project template for phaser3 in typescript
https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-typescript-project-template, and it works fine. So I just run `npm install socket.io-client --save`, and change my game.ts to import io function, as code below. Since v3, socket.io-client doesn't need a separate package type, as said in this doc. So I just had imported in my game.ts file and the types are working in vscode autocomple, and tsc compiler just works, but I'm getting error when generating bundle with `rollup --config rollup.config.dev.js`

The error:

```
> rollup --config rollup.config.dev.js
./src/game.ts → ./dist/game.js...
(!) Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
src/game.ts: (3:9)
[!] Error: 'io' is not exported by node_modules/socket.io-client/build/index.js, imported by src/game.ts
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
src/game.ts (3:9)
1: import { __extends } from "tslib";
2: import 'phaser';
3: import { io } from "socket.io-client";
            ^
4: var Demo = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
5:     __extends(Demo, _super);
Error: 'io' is not exported by node_modules/socket.io-client/build/index.js, imported by src/game.ts
    at error (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:4528:30)
    at Module.error (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9935:16)
    at Module.traceVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:10328:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:8783:39)
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:2622:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:2622:38)
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:2622:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:2622:38)
    at Identifier$1.bind (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:3977:40)
    at CallExpression$1.bind (/mnt/hdd/Meus Códigos/freeboard/client-ts/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:2709:23)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! freetable@0.0.1 dev: `rollup --config rollup.config.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the freetable@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/felipe/.npm/_logs/2021-01-31T18_45_41_975Z-debug.log
```

my rollup config:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

export default {

    //  Our games entry point (edit as required)
    input: [
        './src/game.ts'
    ],

    //  Where the build file is to be generated.
    //  Most games being built for distribution can use iife as the module type.
    //  You can also use 'umd' if you need to ingest your game into another system.
    //  The 'intro' property can be removed if using Phaser 3.21 or above. Keep it for earlier versions.
    output: {
        file: './dist/game.js',
        name: 'MyGame',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
        intro: 'var global = window;'
    },

    plugins: [

        //  Toggle the booleans here to enable / disable Phaser 3 features:
        replace({
            'typeof CANVAS_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
            'typeof WEBGL_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
            'typeof EXPERIMENTAL': JSON.stringify(true),
            'typeof PLUGIN_CAMERA3D': JSON.stringify(false),
            'typeof PLUGIN_FBINSTANT': JSON.stringify(false),
            'typeof FEATURE_SOUND': JSON.stringify(true)
        }),

        //  Parse our .ts source files
        resolve({
            extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx' ]
        }),

        //  We need to convert the Phaser 3 CJS modules into a format Rollup can use:
        commonjs({
            include: [
                'node_modules/eventemitter3/**',
                'node_modules/phaser/**',
            ],
            exclude: [ 
                'node_modules/phaser/src/polyfills/requestAnimationFrame.js',
            ],
            sourceMap: true,
            ignoreGlobal: true
        }),

        //  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2 for config options
        typescript(),

        //  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-serve for config options
        serve({
            open: true,
            contentBase: 'dist',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 10001,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        })

    ]
};
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

ps: sockewt.io-client has an index.js (which is set as "main" in its package.json) and a index.d.ts. The index.d.ts do exports "io", but rollup seems to be looking for exports only in index.js. I need to say to rollup for use index.d.ts instead.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error attempting to use the [`astar-typescript`](https://github.com/digitsensitive/astar-typescript/) library in a project based on the same template.  I also tried changing the template to use `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` instead of `rollup-plugin-commonjs` with no difference.

Comment: I switched my project to use webpack instead rollup and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the 'rollup-commonjs-plugin' to convert your imported library's modules into a format Rollup can use:

In your rollup config edit the part concerning the commonjs-plugin:

```
    commonjs({
        include: [
            'node_modules/eventemitter3/**',
            'node_modules/phaser/**',
            'node_modules/socket.io-client/**',
        ],
        exclude: [ 
            'node_modules/phaser/src/polyfills/requestAnimationFrame.js',
        ],
        sourceMap: true,
    }),
```